# How to make text only copyable and not shareable

Tags: react-native, text

I am new to React Native. I have this code where content is divided into pages. Content is expected to be copied either a specific portion or all page content.

```html
<Text
  selectable={true}
  selectionColor="orange"
  style={[
    styles.textInput,
    {
      fontSize: fontSizeOfBookRead,
      fontWeight: fontWeightOfBookRead,
      fontFamily: "NotoReg",
      textAlign: translations.defaultValue === "en" ? "right" : "left",
      flex: 1,
    },
  ]}
>
  {renderHighlightedText(formattedPageWords, highlightedText)}
</Text>
```

I tried everything to disable system modal for share, copy, but nothing seems to work.